# virtuoso sponger bulk upload

Tags: upload, rdf, virtuoso

I would like to upload to virtuso some rdf/xml files. As I see, I have to load them through sponger in the WebDAV rdf_sink folder.

The data of each file are stored by default in http://local.virt/DAV/home/user/rdf_sink/file.rdf
which is different for each file.

How should I upload my files under the same graph?

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: I would like to follow a similiar process to the one in http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader, as I have a large number of files. The problem is my files are rdf/xml.

Answer (score 1):

[Bulk Loader](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader) which you mentioned in a comment should work just fine for rdf/xml

Answer (score 1):

[Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)'s [Bulk Loader](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader) supports all of the following file formats and filename extensions --

```
.grdf   Geospatial RDF
.nq     N-Quads
.nt     N-Triples
.owl    OWL
.rdf    RDF/XML
.trig   TriG
.ttl    Turtle
.xml    RDF/XML
```

Any of these may be compressed with `gzip` (so have the extra `.gz` filename extension); the Bulk Loader will automatically handle the decompression.

ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producers of Virtuoso. We provide a number of support resources which may get faster response than posts on third party sites, including the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), [public Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), and [confidential Support Cases](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).